# Can I set a delay on Mission Control Hot Corners? Or maybe change how they’re triggered?

Tags: mission-control

I love using Hot Corners, but I regularly trigger them by mistake when performing other tasks, so I disabled them for a while and found I couldn’t live without this functionality.

This got me to thinking - what if I could set a delay (0.5 secs) before the Hot Corners get triggered, or maybe set it so it’s triggered by a right-click action?

I had a look at the Mission Control system preferences but didn’t see any way to do this instead of just accidentally moving the mouse..

Can I do this? Maybe a terminal command? Other suggestions welcome too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes!** When setting up your Hot Corners in System Preferences, just hold down a modifier key.  For example, pressing the ⌘ key while clicking on a corner means you’ll configure it so it’s only triggered while also holding down the ⌘ key.

Comment: At that point, why not just use a keyboard combo?
Maybe it's possible to swap out a different screen locker in OSX that's reasonably configurable?